# How to configure 2 ip address on the same interface

Tags: linux, openwrt

I want to configure my lan interface of the router with 2 IP address.

My router has OpenWRT as firmware

How to edit my openwrt config file inorder to have 2 ip address on the same lan interface?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; probably belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Comment: And it totally does not belong over on Serverfault under any circumstances.

Comment: See the official OpenWrt [documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network#aliasesthe.new.way).

Answer (score 3):

ifconfig is a quite deprecated tool.
Today we have iproute2 suite which, for many reasons, is much better than ifconfig&co.
For example with iproute2 you don't have to use the "trick" of a virtual interface to have more the one ip address on the same physical interface:

`ip addr add IP dev eth0`

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged "linux" in your question, I guess OpenWRT is Linux based.
On Linux, you can do aliases to your eth0 interface. For example, to add an IP to an existing `eth0` interface which has already one configured IP, you can do something like:

```
# ifconfig eth0:1 newIP ... rest of parameters ... (from root)
```

It would help if you add a sample of your configuration file to the question.